# Types/Kinds Confusion in Haskell (Maybe) in Algebraic Data Types

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, data-kinds

I've been working on building my own [Diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomacy_(game)) simulator in Haskell to get my feet wet.

I believe I've come up with a decent definition for what an order is:

```
data Order = Hold Unit Territory
           | Move Unit Territory Territory
           | Support Unit Territory Unit Territory Territory
           | Convoy Fleet Territory Army Territory Territory
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

For those not familiar with the game, the orders are written in the form of "Hold Fleet London", "Move Fleet London English Channel", "Support Fleet English Channel Fleet North Atlantic Ocean Mid Atlantic Ocean" or "Convoy Fleet English Channel Army London Brest", etc.

Now, with the definition of Unit as `data Unit = Fleet | Army (deriving Eq, Show)`, I'm getting the error `Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Fleet'` with regard to my definition of Order.

Why is this?

How can should I write my definitions for Units or Orders (or should I do something different) that allows me to require that the first argument to Convoy be a Fleet and the third argument be an Army?

Am I just "not even wrong" with my approach to this problem?

Should I approach this in my validation function (because there's no WAY to specify only valid orders via Haskell, so far as I know. It's expressive but not THAT expressive)?

I already tried using "DataKinds", but that didn't help me at all (despite the error postscript suggesting to do so, then again, Haskell error postscripts suggest a lot of things, so I doubt I need to pay too much heed to it).

Comment: I'm kind of confused with the terminology. You show your error while using datatypes but then ask how to make Fleet into a typeclass? Anyways, you're getting the error because `Fleet` is not a type, it is a constructor of the type `Unit`. I think you should rethink your design a little bit. Also, `DataKinds` are definitely not what you want. They're an advanced feature which does not apply here.

Comment: Oh, I...kind of forgot I said that. Thanks for that. Update now fixed this.

Answer (score 4):

```
data Unit = Fleet | Army
```

`Unit` is a type. Its values can be either `Fleet` or `Army` -- these are not types.

```
data Order = Hold Unit Territory
           | Move Unit Territory Territory
           | Support Unit Territory Unit Territory Territory
                     ^^^^           ^^^^
```

These are types -- OK.

```
           | Convoy Fleet Territory Army Territory Territory
                    ^^^^^           ^^^^
```

These are values -- not OK. The line above is quite similar to

```
           | Convoy "hello" Territory 42 Territory Territory
```

which makes no sense.

You might simply want to use

```
           | Convoy Territory Territory Territory
```

but I'm not familiar with the game, so I don't know what you actually need there.

Also, forget with typeclasses and the `DataKinds` extension -- don't use advanced stuff unless you really need it.

---

As another option, if you do plan to add fields to `Fleet` and `Army`, is to turn them into types

```
data Fleet = F String Int -- dummy fields, you can put none
data Army = A
data Unit = FleetUnit Fleet | ArmyUnit Army    -- added the types here
data Order = Hold Unit Territory
           | Move Unit Territory Territory
           | Support Unit Territory Unit Territory Territory
           | Convoy Fleet Territory Army Territory Territory
```

Now the last line is ok. The price for this is that you need to use more "wrapping" constructors to build an order, e.g.

```
orderExample1 :: Order
orderExample1 = Convoy (F "test" 33) terr1 A terr2 terr3

orderExample2 :: Order
orderExample2 = Support (FleetUnit (F "test2" 55)) terr1 (ArmyUnit A) terr2 terr3
```

Above, `F ...` builds a `Fleet`, then `FleetUnit ...` turns it into a `Unit`, and finally `Support ...` turns that into an `Order`.

Comment: I just edited my post to clarify a little bit more on that. Judging by that, I think I'll just go the validation function route (read the edit). Also, I didn't know that typeclasses and DataKinds were advanced (granted I don't even know what's advanced anymore with this language...it took me a couple full days to try to understand what the whole Peano arithmetic thing with (+) being defined in terms of Succ...oy vey), I've seen them all over the place in error screens.

Comment: I guess the main question is: do `Fleet` and `Army` have any fields? As written above, they carry no information with them. If such, what would be the gain in passing a `Fleet` argument to `Convoy`, if you already know that that is the only value that argument can have?

Comment: Right now, they don't have any fields, but I may change that. I can't decide whether or not I want a given Territory (basically a location, so English Channel would be a Territory) to Maybe have a Unit associated with it or if I want a Unit to have a Territory associated with it. I was hoping to be able to do something like being able to write  `Convoy (eliminate $ unit someTerritory) someTerritory otherTerritory` or something of the sort (where eliminate just removes the Just from a Maybe or throws an error

Comment: See the edit. If you want to add fields you can use more types to do what you want.

Comment: Is there any way to do something like one would in OOP, deriving a data type? Basically saying Fleet and Army are both Units, without having to rebuild them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118854/discussion-between-jack-brandt-and-chi).